Creating a new bank account for the user
Are we able to create a new account for a user using Banno, and if so, are we also able to delete/deactivate that account?
I know we can view user account information and edit the account name, but I need to know if we can create a new account.

No, Banno's APIs don't include any ability to create/enroll a new user nor is there any ability to delete/deactivate the account via the API.
We have this page that describes the Identity use case and it has info on the sweet spot for Banno's Authentication Framework: https://jackhenry.dev/use-cases/identity/
